# MergDataGridScroller: How to save + restore position?

Tags: livecode

Is there an easy way to save the vertical/horizontal scroll position of the datagrid scroller used inside the MergDataGridScroller?  Want to be able to go back to the same card and have the datagrid open at the same location as it previously was.

It seems that the datagrid scroller is created/destroyed on the open/close-Card cycle, otherwise I could just hide it.

Perhaps this is one of those situations where it's easier to "roll my own"?

Any help appreciated - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes the scroller is created and destroyed as you open and close cards. I think this is something that should be supported but isn't currently. Basically it's just a matter of not resetting the scroll of the group and then setting the native scroller to the scroll of the group when it's created. Should just be a couple of tweaks to the handleLayout command in the behaviour. I'm not sure about maintaining scroll when the content rect changes. I can look at that too.

So in answer to you question rather than roll your own you have a couple of choices:

- Wait for me to do it and release a new version
- Edit the behaivior script with whatever changes you like

EDIT

I've done this now ;-)

Comment: Any more hints? I've been battling trying to work it out and can't quite figure it out. Doesn't seem quite as simple as you describe (though that could just be me!).